# Download File with Specific Version-ID from AWS S3 using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to download file that has many versions from version-enabled bucket. Using the bellow code, it always download the file that has latest version.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket("mybucket")
bucket.download_file("somefile", "/donwload/path/somefile.txt")
```

How can I specify which version I want to download for the "somefile" file?

Comment: Try specifying the `VersionId` in `ExtraArgs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments, `Bucket.download_file` has an `ExtraArgs` parameter, where you can specify additional parameters that are passed down to the `Client.get_object` function that `download_file` wraps. From the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) of `get_object`, you can see that the relevant argument is `VersionId`.

```py
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket("mybucket")
bucket.download_file(
    "somefile",
    "/donwload/path/somefile.txt",
    ExtraArgs={"VersionId": "my_version"}
)
```